# React routing not rendering home page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a wrapper component called Layout.

```
  class Layout extends React.Component{
      render(){
        return(
          <div className="container-fluid">

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Layout;
```

And then an App component which acts as a HomePage.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <Header />
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <UserViewer/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8">
          <ImageViewer/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is my routes configuration

```
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={Layout} >
    <IndexRoute component={App}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Route>

);
```

This is the entry point to my application.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The App component never gets rendered on the page, even on the React Tab of my browser I can't see the app component getting rendered.

Comment: Try to render `{this.props.children}` inside of your Layout component.

Comment: Yes, `{this.props.children}` inside the `<div className="container-fluid">`.